# CentOS 7 TeamViewer RPM Install Failes on QT5 WebKit

Tags: centos7

Installing teamviewer-host.x86_64.rpm on CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 yum produced the following errors:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: qt5-qtwebkit-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
Requires: qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.6.2
Installing: qt5-qtbase-5.9.2-3.el7.x86_64 (base)
qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.9.2-3.el7
Error: Package: qt5-qtwebkit-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
Requires: qt5-qtdeclarative(x86-64) = 5.6.2
Installing: qt5-qtdeclarative-5.9.2-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
qt5-qtdeclarative(x86-64) = 5.9.2-1.el7
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I fixed it by:

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/testing/7/x86_64/Packages/q/qt5-qtwebkit-5.9.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
 yum install qt5-qtwebkit-5.9.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum install teamviewer-host.x86_64.rpm
```

Then everything worked fine.

Comment: You'll need to wait a few days for EPEL to update.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason everything on epel has been update to 5.9.2 except for qtwebkit. The new location is http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/q/qt5-qtwebkit-5.9.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 1):

Just posting this answer because I debugged and searched all day so maybe someone else won't have to.  It is probably a temporary repo issue while epel upgrades qt5.2 to qt5.9